# How do I align the Figure tag and the caption on the same line

Tags: captions

I am using an pdf on my LaTeX report and somehow when I add the caption the tag and the caption statement are a little bit mis-aligned.
[image: Figure tag and Caption misaligned]

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
     \leavevmode
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/mypdf}
      \caption{caption here}
     \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I am actually using a template made by my university department which might be causing some misalignment but is there a hack around this? is `\sloppy` able to solve this? if so how?

### Note

The above figure is inside a `description` block

```
\begin{description}
     \item ITEM1
       %% Above mentioned figure code
 \end{description}
```

## Update: HACK around

So it turns out if I write :

```
\caption{TWIN nodes placed in rooms of the South Block NW1 building, University of Bremen}
```

The misalignment occurs as above. but if I trim down the caption:

```
\caption{TWIN nodes placed in rooms of the South Block NW1 building}
```

the Line completely fits within the page spacing criterion of the template.
This is a dirty hack but it has to do some thing with the page margins.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There must be something else which redefines how the `caption` is placed, either in you code or in the template you are using. If the latter is the case, I doubt you should change it if you are handing it in to the university as they probably like their own style. In any case, an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be handy here.

Comment: Also, don't use the `center` environment: it adds unwanted vertical spacing. You don't need `leavevmode`.

Comment: So it turns out writing long sentences in the description ruins the linebreak feature. Hence I reduced the sentence description. Dirty hack. thanks @Bernard

Comment: Could you post a complete example demonstrating what happens?

Comment: yup will edit the question.